# Dojo FilteringSelect scroll to top on list open

Tags: dojo, scroll, widget

I have an instance of Dojo FilteringSelect widget and whenever I want to open the DropDownList of it - the scroller is exactly where it was when I closed it before.

As it is a good thing when I closed it because of a selection, but if I just closed it by clicking somewhere else - it is a little annoying.

Is there any way of controlling where the scroller will be when I open the Drop Down list?

Comment: Can you replicate this issue in a jsfiddle or something similar? I can't seem to recreate the issue. The FilteringSelect always is scrolled to the top for me.

Comment: open the filteringSelect drop down, scroll to the middle, and then close it (without selection), and again open it. You will be scrolled to the same place where it was when you scrolled it, but if you insist: http://jsfiddle.net/GAuaw/ which is from Dojo Documentation.